# Heroku app crashed because of eslint faulty import

Tags: express, heroku, npm, eslint, package.json

I am developing an app which uses VueJS to display the views and ExpressJS acting as the server.

Works fine locally so far, but after successfully deploying it on Heroku it does not load the app and crashes the dyno.

My folder structure is as such:

- project root

  - client

    - package.json for client
  - server

    - package.json for server
  - package.json that tells Heroku to install dependences in both folders

This is the package.json that Heroku refers to to build the whole app:

```
{
    "name": "my-app",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "scripts": {
        "postinstall": "npm install --prefix server && npm install --prefix client"
    }
}
```

package.json for the server:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./src/app.js",
  "scripts": {
      "start": "./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js src/app.js --exec 'npm run lint && node'",
  "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint **/*.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
  "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
  "cors": "^2.8.4",
  "eslint": "^4.12.1",
  "express": "^4.16.2",
  "morgan": "^1.9.0",
  "nodemon": "^1.12.5",
  "pg": "^7.4.0",
  "sequelize": "^4.27.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1"
}
}
```

I checked the logs and the issue stands in the eslint library, which Heroku cannot find in my project. Any idea on how to solve this issue?

```
2017-12-08T14:55:35.408127+00:00 app[web.1]: Cannot find module 'eslint-config-standard'
2017-12-08T14:55:35.408145+00:00 app[web.1]: Referenced from: /app/server/.eslintrc.js
2017-12-08T14:55:35.408945+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'eslint-config-standard'
2017-12-08T14:55:35.408947+00:00 app[web.1]: Referenced from: /app/server/.eslintrc.js
2017-12-08T14:55:35.408948+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ModuleResolver.resolve (/app/server/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/module-resolver.js:74:19)
2017-12-08T14:55:35.408949+00:00 app[web.1]:     at resolve (/app/server/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:471:25)
2017-12-08T14:55:35.408950+00:00 app[web.1]:     at load (/app/server/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:542:26)
2017-12-08T14:55:35.408951+00:00 app[web.1]:     at configExtends.reduceRight (/app/server/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:421:36)
2017-12-08T14:55:35.408951+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Array.reduceRight (<anonymous>)
2017-12-08T14:55:35.408952+00:00 app[web.1]:     at applyExtends (/app/server/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:403:28)
2017-12-08T14:55:35.408953+00:00 app[web.1]:     at loadFromDisk (/app/server/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:514:22)
2017-12-08T14:55:35.408953+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.load (/app/server/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:550:20)
2017-12-08T14:55:35.408954+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Config.getLocalConfigHierarchy (/app/server/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:228:44)
2017-12-08T14:55:35.408955+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Config.getConfigHierarchy (/app/server/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:180:43)
2017-12-08T14:55:35.464317+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-12-08T14:55:35.464681+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2017-12-08T14:55:35.466080+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! server@1.0.0 lint: `eslint **/*.js`
2017-12-08T14:55:35.466205+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2017-12-08T14:55:35.466413+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2017-12-08T14:55:35.466555+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 lint script.
2017-12-08T14:55:35.466726+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-12-08T14:55:35.491352+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-12-08T14:55:35.491535+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2017-12-08T14:55:35.491648+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2017-12-08T14_55_35_468Z-debug.log
2017-12-08T14:55:35.506231+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
2017-12-08T14:56:08.700333+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/status" host=babbelbord.herokuapp.com request_id=f86a8552-14b5-477c-b79d-d575ad30bffa fwd="84.81.81.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer thanks to Heroku support. The problem was that my dependencies were defined in the `devDependencies` of the package.json file, while they should be declared in `dependencies` for Heroku to properly work.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be referencing `eslint-config-standard` from within `/app/server/.eslintrc.js`, however your package.json doesn't have any dependencies.

You will want to run `npm install eslint-config-standard --save` which will create a dependency entry in your package.json. Then you should be save to commit the changes and deploy to heroku again.

Because you've not declared your dependency within the package.json, your dyno will not know to install it. I suspect you've simply forgotten to add the `--save` flag onto your original `npm install` and so it's only installed into your `node_modules` folder without making the entry in the `package.json`.

Comment: Thanks for helping Elliot. However, I checked and I already had that package in the devDependencies. I update the question with the server package.json file if it can help you

Comment: Can you provide the code from `/app/server/.eslintrc.js`? That would be really helpful as it's the code producing the error it seems.

Comment: It would also be useful to know what command your procfile is invoking as well :)

Comment: This is the .eslintrc.js file content: 

module.exports = {
    "extends": "standard"
};

Comment: And this is the content of the Procfile: web: npm start --prefix server

Comment: The error shows that heroku is running the `eslint` command. Since your procfile indicates that you're running `npm start` on the server directory, I'd say you're probably missing something in the logs. Are you able to get more of the logs so we can see the entire deployment process from the moment you run `git push heroku master`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160839/discussion-between-the-condor-and-elliot-blackburn).